# Choice of Conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

Could you help me with Conditionals?

Let's say it's Tuesday and I say to my friend:

> I planned to visit Jane on Friday but I heard she'd gone on holiday.

Can I paraphrase the above sentence with Conditional II?

> I **would be visiting** Jane on Friday but I heard she had gone on holiday.

Now it's Saturday of the same week and I say

> I **would have visited** Jane on Friday but I heard she had gone on holiday.

That is Conditional III

Is my way of thinking correct? Does it sound OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally prefer slightly more verbose answers, but there's not much to say here. Yes, all three of those are fine. There are variations that could be made on phrasing, but none of them are general improvements.

With the information you have provided, those are all fine.